# POST validation fails due to path required, but i do have the path

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I'm trying to build a REST API that stores famous quotes and their authors. The GET method seems to work fine, but when I try to use the POST method i receive a error. Also it kinda works when i remove the 'require: true' from the quote Schema, but neither the quote or author are returned just the id

here is the error:

```
{
  "message": "Quote validation failed: cite: Path `cite` is required."
}
```

My attempt to post. I'm using the extesion called REST client:

```
POST  http://localhost:3000/quotes
Content-Type: application.json

{
    "cite": "Accept the things to which fate binds you, and love the people with whom fate brings you together,but do so with all your heart.",
    "author": "Marcus Aurelius"
}
```

The function used:

```
const express = require('express')
const Quote = require('../models/quote')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', async (req,res) => {
    const quote = new Quote({
        cite: req.body.cite,
        author: req.body.author
    })
    try {
        const newQuote = await quote.save()
        res.status(201).json(newQuote)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({message: err.message})
    }
})
```

And the object Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const quoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    cite: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
    }
})

module.exports =mongoose.model('Quote', quoteSchema)
```

Comment: I don't see a request handler for the path `quotes` in the POST request. I have no idea how your request and the code relate to the error message `"Quote validation failed: cite: Path \`cite\` is required."`

Comment: Isn't that `application/json` instead of `application.json`?

Comment: I can't believe i was head banging my desk trying to find the error and it was just this. Thx guys and sorry for waisting your time on  small stuff